# Summer '24: Data Extension Field Limits for "sendable fields". What is a "sendable field"?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Just read this in the release notes: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2024_spring_cab_de_restriction.htm&type=5. All it says is:

> To improve performance when using sendable data extensions in new and existing sends and journeys, **the length of sendable fields is now limited to 254 characters**. This limit is enforced with the Summer ’24 release.

What is a "sendable field"? Or does this in fact mean ALL fields in a sendable data extension are limited to 254 chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the field used in the sendable relationship

Comment: As in the "[field name] relates to SubscriberKey on subscriber" (or however it goes, don't have the exact wording in front of me).

Comment: Ok this doc mentions sendable fields: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_c360a_data_extensions.htm&type=5